# PUSH通知。「アプリ宛てに作成」エラー

Tags: android, push-notification

初心者です。
PUSH通知機能を設定したいのですが、クラウドのアイコンにある「プッシュ通知」をダブルクリックして、「アプリ宛に作成」 をクリックして、「追加」をクリックすると

> 通知情報の登録に失敗：There are no target devices

と表示されて追加できません。
何が原因なのでしょうか？（AndroidManifest.xmlにを記入済み。Google API Console で GCM を有効化。コレクションを追加済みです。）
PUSH通知の設定等は色々なところにあって、どこから手をつけていいのか分かりません。
どなたか、分かる方お願いします。